# SharePoint prompting credentials for every external URL

Tags: 2007, windows-authentication

Each time when I try to browse SharePoint site using external URL it ask for windows credential.

When using default (internal) URL, credentials are not asked.

How to make SharePoint not ask credentials when accessing external URL?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your setup and the approaches you have already tried to resolve the problem? We need more to go on to help you.

Comment: when we browse sharepoint site using default(internal) URL,it dosn't ask for credential but when try to browse using external URL which we have added in iis binding it ask credential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have your default(internal) URL set as Trusted site (or Local Intranet) in IE settings, making IE to automatically login using your Windows credentials. Add external URL to Trusted sites or Local Intranet and you should no longer get login prompt.